# how to permanently merge two measurements in InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb

Have a set of temperature sensors in my house and I've just upgraded them, to new devices.

They record exactly the same way into my InfluxDB (ie temperature and humidity every 15 mins), but the device names are different in the InfluxDB.

I'm keen not to lose years of history, so I'd like to rename all my historical records from TempSensor to the new name which is ESP_TempSensor (and thus merge the records) - there's no overlap as I literally swapped the devices and data format is identical.

I've googled and I know InfluxDB doesn't seem very capable at joins and other simple things, but in this case I'm happy to manually and permanently merge the datasets.

Any pointers/help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `INTO` clause:

`SELECT * INTO ESP_TempSensor FROM TempSensor GROUP BY *`

Make sure you include the `GROUP BY *` otherwise influx will convert all tags into field keys.

Comment: Thanks! Think this should do the trick, I've tried it but am getting 'database required' error, I've then tried explicitly declaring with: SELECT * INTO ESP_TempGardenRoom FROM “home_assistant”.“autogen”."GardenRoom" GROUP BY *  but it returns a 400 error. Any ideas?

Comment: @Alphatester77 maybe try `use [ "<database_name>" | "<database_name>"."<retention policy_name>" ]` first. Then influx will know which database you're referring to, without the need to specify retention policy etc. I think the issue with your syntax maybe that influx knows WHERE to get the measurements from, but it is unsure where to put it. But that's just a guess...

Comment: Ah useful - that sort of makes sense, I'm just struggling with the influx terminology for things - ok no laughing at my attempt, but I've uploaded a screenshot of the chronograf query screen so you can see the db structure/fields. Are you able to give me any pointers on my sql?  https://imgur.com/62IfaaK

Comment: I'm trying to use: SELECT * INTO ["home_assistant.autogen"."autogen"] ESPTemp_GardenRoom FROM GardenRoom GROUPBY * - but that doesn't work!

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the query you entered as well? This is Chronograf, right? Have you tried the influx cli as well ? Usually the response should contain WHY the query failed ... I could imagine that your request failed because Chronograf will send a GET request which will fail, since you want to actually write data so you will have to send a POST request. But this is just a guess, really annoying chronograf doesn't actually give you the information from the http response...

Comment: Try this : `curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:8086/query?db=home_assisant' --data-urlencode 'q=SELECT * INTO "ESP_TempSensor" FROM "GardenRoom" GROUP BY *'`

Comment: Yep - here's a screengrab: https://imgur.com/2YHzMfL just really gives me a 400 error - as you say, not very helpful!  Haven't tried the influx cli - could try that next?

Comment: PS I've tried above query and it doesn't work in chronograf (it seems to rewrite the port names into other variables, eg it just changes to say: curl -XPOST 'http:upperDashboardTime://localhost:upperDashboardTime:/query?db=home_assisant' --data-urlencode 'q=SELECT * INTO "ESP_TempSensor" FROM "GardenRoom" GROUP BY *'

Comment: The curl command was meant to be used from the terminal, not via chronograf.

Comment: Ok apologies for the delay - this is helpful, I've done this through the CLI and it 'seems' to be working in some shape, ie I get the following response: {"results":[{"statement_id":0,"series":[{"name":"result","columns":["time","written"],"values":[["1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",0]]}]}]}   Does this mean anything to you? I can't see any obvious data being moved by charts updating with history. Any smart ways to check most welcome!

Comment: Usually the response should contain the number of points that were written.. Looks like something didn't quite work out. Did you try querying the data? `SELECT * FROM ESP_TempSensor WHERE time<{timestamp before the installation of the new sensor}` If this returns anything the data was successfully moved into the new measurement ...

Comment: Yes - or rather I can see this in chronograf - very cleanly can see the before and after (ie data not moved!) - check two screens here: https://imgur.com/a/c7GSoik  Feels such a simple thing to do that I'm struggling with here! I don't know if there's any GUI tools like toad I could use here - there's not even a huge volume of data to cut and paste!

Comment: In fact, found DBeaver connects to InfluxDB, so have tried through this - getting 0 written on the simple query, so looks like it's not finding any matches: https://imgur.com/a/IZgXClE